# symfony2 {% render (controller()) %}

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my main layout, i render another controller like this:

```
{# main layout.html.twig #}
<div id="login">
    {% render(controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:login")) %}
</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
```

this controller generate differents variables (lastUserName, csrf_token, error), Now how can i use these variables in my main layout.html.twig?

Comment: Not possible, as render returns the resulting html response.

Comment: Mumm, I explain:
I want to display error message in the main div, by i don't find the way to get error message in my layout twig??

Comment: is there any other way to include FSOUserBundle:Security:login in my main layout? by the way sorry for my bad english :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not intended by the symfony developers.

render() should render exactly one template if possible. This template should extend other templates. So what you can do is:

```
// FOSUserBundle:Security:login (Template)
{% extends main_layout.html.twig %}

{{ someVariable }}
{% block someName %}  
    YOUR DESIGN
{% endblock %}

// FOSUserBundle:Security:login (Template)    
SOME DESIGN
{{ someVariable }}
{% block someName %}  
    empty
{% endblock %}
SOME DESIGN
```

The variable someVariable is useable in main_layout and in the login template. You inject all variables when rendering the child template in the controller ($this -> render('templateName',array()))